# Rails build fields_for once inside fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, fields-for

in my

```
<%= nested_form_for @object do |f| %>
```

I've a nested_form like:

```
<%=f.fields_for :nested, :url => { :action => "new" } do |build| %>
   <%= render 'nested_fields', :f => build %>
<% end %>
```

and inside that nested_field, I've another fields_for :nested2

My Problem is: I want nested2 appearing 1 time, when nested is called.
I tried inside the new action of the nested controller the

```
@nested = Nested.new
@nested.nested2.build
```

but this does only work for the "real" new action.
Is there any solution for that problem?

I'm using the "nested_form" gem.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what you're asking. Are you trying to create a form for your `obkect` (typo?), that then has a new `nested` object in it, with that `nested` object also have a nested form for a new `nested2`? Also, what's with the `:url => { :action => "new" }` in your `fields_for` call?

Comment: yes you are right - that was just a typo. I corrected it now. The form is for object and it has the nested inside. This nested can be added as often as I click on the link. For example: I've an invoice with as many articles as I want. To combine them, I use a separate table with the invoice_id and the article_id and also the count of the articles. Now when I want to add a new invoice with new articles, I need to fill out the "count" field in the separate table. Hope now it's a little more clear what I try to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fields_for` lets you specify a particular object to render the fields for, so if you want your `nested_fields` partial to contain nested fields for a single, newly build `nested2` model, you can do it in the `fields_for` call itself, like this:

```
# '_nested_fields.html.erb'

...
<%= f.fields_for :nested2, f.object.build_nested2 do |build| %>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```

This is assuming that `Nested` `has_one :nested2`, if it's a `has_many` association the `fields_for` arguments would be slightly different:

```
<%= f.fields_for :nested2s, f.object.nested2s.build do |build| %>
```

`f.object` allows you to access the form builder's object, and you can then use it's association methods (based on the association type) to build the new object at that point.

Comment: In my case it's a has_many association. What do I have to change at this argument?

Comment: I've updated my answers to cover either situation. From your description above though, I don't quite understand why you'd need a has_many association (although I think I'm still missing something about what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: It's nearly exact the situation above I'm trying to realise. I've the objects invoices, articles and "invoice_articles". The last one has "belongs_to" accociations and the first two has both "has_many :through" associations. Your changed solution raises the following exception: undefined method `invoice_articles'

Comment: So `Invoice` `has_many :articles, through: :invoice_articles`, and `Article` `has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_articles`? Do they both have `has_many :invoice_articles`?

Comment: exactly - that's my actual association schema. And in invoice and article, I added "accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_articles" as well

Comment: Actually, just realised I made an error when I updated the answer. It should be `f.object.nested2s.build` instead of `f.nested2s.build`. If you did that, then I'm assuming the `undefined error` was actually for the builder object (full error would have made that easier to spot).

Comment: that's not working for me, too... currently my code looks like http://pastebin.com/Lf9RZWhd. I don't think, that the error really helps.... (http://pastebin.com/Dw0bC3Q8)

Comment: Ah, it should be `g.object...`, not `g.invoice...` -- you want the form builders `object`.

Comment: oh damn... that's a bit embarrassing now... I thought you are using the names of my original posting.. now it's loading the 2nd nested form on calling the first one. The only problem now is, that the values are now saved one time correctly and one time without the :count. and that's while in the models of invoice and articles I've set " accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_articles, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:count].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true". If I set " validates_presence_of :count" at the "invoice_articles", it raises always an error..

Comment: You mean you're getting two `invoice_articles` saved, one with the count from the form and a second one with no count? I'd wondered if that would happen, as I'm assuming it's creating the blank one automatically because of the through association. It would probably work if you ordered the objects the other way around (ie nest `invoice_article` inside the `invoice` form, and nest `article` within the `invoice_article` fields, as that way you shouldn't get the extra object being created. You should be able to re-order the fields so that it still looks the same.

Comment: The problem according to my view is the following: I want two possibilities to add new articles to my invoice: the first one is tho choose the article from a dropdown. There are only articles possible who are already existing. The 2nd one is the one, I described up to now: to create a new article while creating a new invoice. Because of that, I've two "invoice_article" nested forms on my page. Maybe it's a better idea to replace the dropdown by click with a nested form for the articles to create a new one. What do you think?

Comment: In case anyone is working on @ZaidCrouch's approach about nesting the objects the other way around, that kind of works, but it's not truly satisfactory. The main limitation is that if you want to edit an existing `invoice_article`, you are always building a new `article`, so you end up with blank fields rather than what you'd previously put in for `article`.

Comment: What I have done is use some conditions: `<% if build.object.nested2 %> #the form without f.object.nested2.build <% else %> #the form *with* f.object.nested2.build %> <% end %>`. So far as I can tell, this works.